# Why is happening this weird behaviour between Animations and HorizontalMotionEffects?

Tags: swift, uiviewanimation

I was testing out some code and ended up with this piece of code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

 @IBOutlet var backgroundImageView: UIImageView!

 override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)
    hideAndShow()
 }

 func hideAndShow(){
    self.backgroundImageView.alpha = 0
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0, options: .Repeat | .AllowUserInteraction | .Autoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: { [weak self] in
        self?.backgroundImageView.alpha = 1
        }, completion: nil)
 }

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.backgroundImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center;
    self.backgroundImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "640x1136launch")!)
    self.addParallaxEffectToView(self.backgroundImageView)
    self.backgroundImageView.frame = CGRectInset(self.backgroundImageView.frame, -50, -50);
 }

 func addParallaxEffectToView(view: UIView ) {
    // Set vertical effect
    var verticalMotionEffect = UIInterpolatingMotionEffect(keyPath: "center.y", type: UIInterpolatingMotionEffectType.TiltAlongVerticalAxis)
    verticalMotionEffect.minimumRelativeValue = -50
    verticalMotionEffect.maximumRelativeValue = 50

    // Set horizontal effect
    var horizontalMotionEffect = UIInterpolatingMotionEffect(keyPath: "center.x", type: UIInterpolatingMotionEffectType.TiltAlongHorizontalAxis)
    horizontalMotionEffect.minimumRelativeValue = -50
    horizontalMotionEffect.maximumRelativeValue = -50

    // Create group to combine both
    var group = UIMotionEffectGroup.new()
    group.motionEffects = [horizontalMotionEffect, verticalMotionEffect]

    // Add both effects to your view
    view.addMotionEffect(group);
 }
}
```

What this code was supposed to do is to make a **blinking effect** over an `UIImage` that I have on my `UIViewController`.

This image also has an **UIMotionEffect** (***tilt*** in this case) that works perfect to me when tilting the device vertically but for some reason does not work when my device is tilted horizontally.

Nevertheless, the point is that when I call to my `hideandShow()` function, my view starts to blink, but also, at the same pace,..starts to move **horizontally**!!!

[image]

Why is this happening? I'm out of ideas.